# How to create a patch file for text files only in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, diff, patch

I have a directory with hundreds of text files and object files. I had a copy of this directory somewhere else and I edited it and recompiled it. the object files are now different, but I want to generate a patch from the text files only. is there a way to do this or do I need to separate them into different folders?

diff -uraN original/ new/ > patch.diff

how can I specify file types in this command?

-X excludes, but I want the opposite of this. I want to exclude everything except .txt files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want one diff per txt?

```
for f in original/*.txt                        # for each original
do  d=${f#original/}                           # get base name
    diff -uraN "$f" "new/$d" > ${d%.txt}.diff  # diff old against new
done
```

You mention `-X`; I'm not sure how `diff` implements it, but the bash CLI allows extended globbing.

```
$: shopt -s extglob
$: ls -l *.???
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089         0 May 10 21:49 OCG3C82.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089         0 May 11 03:22 OCG511D.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089         0 May 12 00:03 OCG5214.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089         0 May 14 09:34 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089         0 May 14 09:34 b.txt

$: ls *.!(txt)
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089         0 May 10 21:49 OCG3C82.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089         0 May 11 03:22 OCG511D.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089         0 May 12 00:03 OCG5214.tmp
```

Comment: I actually wanted all of them in the same patch file, but I would run your script and then combine all of them into one patch file using combinediff

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to perform the `diff` command on any files with the extension `.txt`.

Unfortunately, `diff` has no include option, but we can get around it by using `find` to get a list of the files which aren't text files, and then we can exclude those using `-X`. This one liner will do that.

```
find original new ! -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n' -type f | diff -uraN original/ new/ -X - > patch.diff
```

If you want more info on how that works you can check out the man pages for `find` and `diff`.